# Versões de Constantes de acordo com BuildType

Tags: android, gradle

Eu tenho algumas constantes as quais eu gostaria que variasse de acordo como `BuildType` do Gradle. Entre elas as URL's the das API's que utilizo no meu app, que podem ser de produção, homologação e desenvolvimento. Por exemplo:

> https://api.empresa.com.br e http://dev.api.empresa.com.br

Já li a [documentação](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types), e já tentei soluções [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626305/gradle-android-buildtypes-overriding-each-other) e [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782368/android-gradle-buildtypes-duplicate-class). Mas nenhuma funcionou.

Qual a correta configuração do `build.gradle´ para que eu não tenha que ficar alterando manualmente minhas constantes de acordo com o ambiente.

Answer (score 1):

Tanto as instruções que constam na [documentação](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) quando as soluções que constam nos posts que mencionei funcionam perfeitamente.

O problema é que o Android Studio parece ter um bug, pois ele reconhece apenas as classes do BuildType que está ativo dando a impressão de que os outros pacotes estão com erro.

É necessário utilizar a janela **Build Variant** e selecionar versão em que você quer trabalhar no momento para que eles reconheça as classes e os pacotes.

PS: Descobri esse "bug" graças ao [link](http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html) indicado pelo @NetoMarin, mas não há necessidade alguma de se usar `Flavors` para uma tarefa tão simples.

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar criar arquivos diferentes, para cada conjunto de valores das constantes que quiser usar. E ai, criar tarefas que irão selecionar o arquivo no momento certo.

Isso é feito através da configuração productFlavors, e ai você indica qual para produção e teste, por exemplo.

Depois, na aba de Build Variants do Android Studio para alternar entre as configurações.

Nesse [blog post](http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html) você irá encontrar uma explicação inclusive com imagens.

Comment: Grande Neto! Obrigado pelo link, me ajudou a identificar o problema, mas o autor foi muito equivocado na exemplo de uso das Build Variants. Conforme a documentação oficial, apenas o BuildType já é suficiente para resolver o problema dos ambientes, o `Flavors` é para criar versões alternativas do app como **Paga** e **Grátis**, onde cada um deles terá a versão **dev** e **prod**. Não faz sentido nenhum ter Flavors _ProductionDebug_ ou _StagingRelease_

Comment: Realmente o Flavors está um pouco a mais do que a tarefa se for só para algumas variáveis de ambiente. Que bom que encontrou a solução.